# SQL Server cannot import data

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I had dropped all my primary and foreign keys, I have dropped the tables and recreated them as well. When I try to import data I get his error for 2 of my tables:

> Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
> An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record
> is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
> Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".  (SQL Server
> Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with
> Destination - FactEvent.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[EventID] on
> Destination - FactEvent.Inputs[Destination Input]. The column status
> returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the
> column.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination -
> FactEvent.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code
> 0xC020907D occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination -
> FactEvent.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An
> error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
> There may be error messages posted before this with more information
> about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component
> "Destination - FactEvent" (41) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while
> processing input "Destination Input" (54). The identified component
> returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific
> to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow
> task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this
> with more information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and
> Export Wizard)

Comment: Looks error is due to RI.. For sure you do not have foriegn keys setup?

Comment: @kannankandasamy Yeah, nothing is listed when I go to design and right click Relationships.

Comment: I got same error @Paulie. Is it happen because data problem?